# Not able to retrieve right amount of objects from array in model controller when calling a method to get an array of data count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

In detail, I am retrieving data from firebase and I am creating an array of restaurants objects from each entry received and Im then performing a count on the number of elements are in the array, which should be 5,23: (restaurant #1)has 5 elements in the array,(restaurant #2) 23 (there's only two restaurants in the dataset). This is being done on my model controller which looks like this

```
class OverviewModelController {

  //MARK: - SharedController
  static let sharedController = OverviewModelController()

  //MARK: - Source 
  var restaurantList = [Restaurant]() 
  var filteredList = [Restaurant]()

  //MARK: - FireBase Reference
  var ref: DatabaseReference?

  func fetchAllData() {        
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref?.child("restaurants").observe( .childAdded , with: { (snap) in
        guard let topArray = snap.value as? [[String:Any]] else {print(":(") ; return }
        var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()

        for dictionary in topArray {                
            guard let address = dictionary["address"] as? String,
                let city = dictionary["city"] as? String,
                let inspectionDate = dictionary["inspectionDate"] as? String,
                let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                let major = dictionary["major"] as? Int,
                let minor = dictionary["minor"] as? Int,
                let violationTitle = dictionary["violationTitle"] as? String else { continue }

            //MARK: - creates restaurants from the list above
            let restaurant = Restaurant(address: address, city: city, inspectionDate: inspectionDate, name: name, major: major, minor: minor, violationTitle: violationTitle)

            //MARK: - Adds a restaurant to restaurant array instance
            restaurantArray.append(restaurant)                
        }                      
        self.restaurantList = restaurantArray
       print(self.restaurantList.count)
    })             
}
```

Once I run the method above on a viewcontroller, it prints right count from the view did load but if I check the restaurantList count from a method in the viewController I only get 23 as oppose to 5, 23. I guess I am a bit loss on what I'm doing wrong. I know im doing something that only allows me to receive the last restaurant. I assumed I passed the array of data through the shared controller but it doesn't give me the result I want. The viewcontroller is below:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

  @IBOutlet weak var homeSearchBar: DesignableSearchBar!

  var finalArray = [Restaurant]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FirebaseApp.configure()
   homeSearchBar.delegate = self
    fetch()             
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)        
  }

  func fetch() {         
    OverviewModelController.sharedController.fetchAllData()                    
  }            

  func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {        
    print(OverviewModelController.sharedController.restaurantList.count)

    self.homeSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {          
        self.homeSearchBar.text = ""        
    }                
  }
```

Comment: Did you check that your guard statement in your `fetchAllData()` function isn't pruning out one of your entries due to missing fields or fields with the incorrect type assertion?  Meaning that when your values are returned are they actually an Int or an Int16? `let minor = dictionary["minor"] as? Int16` etc... and do all your `address/city/etc...` fields exist in the data that is returned?

Comment: @digitalHound, the type casting is working because the actual number of objects in the array is reflected when I call the fetchAllData() method but if I try to get the right count from a method in a different file, it only gives me the last object in the array. So, when I call  print(OverviewModelController.sharedController.restaurantList.count) from the searchbarsearchbuttonclicked, I dont get the same count as when I call fetchAllData from the viewDidLoad, which is the right count.

Comment: Hmm ok, do you have any code elsewhere in the app that acts on or manipulates  the contents of the `OverviewModelController.sharedController.restaurantList` array?

Comment: No, only in the files above.